# Error 109 WAT080 : Failed to locate the Windows Azure SDK 2.1 on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have Visual Studio 2013 with update 3 installed.
On the first time i opened my project, it prompted me to download and install
Azure SDK 2.2 and so i did.
When i tried to build, it fails and gives me this error message:

Error   109 WAT080 : Failed to locate the Windows Azure SDK. Please make sure the Windows Azure SDK v2.1 is installed.

So I installed SDK 2.1 but the build still fails with the same error.
These are my installed azure SDKs: 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4.
I also confirmed that the folders of each version are NOT missing here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Windows Azure Tools

We started the cloud project which is an MVC site on the 3rd quarter of 2013 when the Windows Azure 2.2 released and I had no problem.

Is it possible that these Azure SDKs are conflicting?

Comment: Usually problems like this were fixed by re-creating Azure project. Give it a go, might help, might not.

Comment: I have the same problem. Is there anyone who have a suggestion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's fixed now. Unfortunately, you cannot find the Azure SDK 2.2 for VS 2013 and older versions in web platform installer anymore. So you have to manually install all the components (according to version).

I noticed that this folder is missing.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure.NET SDK\v2.2

Which means that WindowsAzureLibsForNet-x64.msi is not yet installed.
You can download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40893.

I've seen solved threads about this but the solution didn't solve for everyone. I hope this would help.

Comment: SDK is not much different, why not update to the latest SDK v2.4?

Comment: Yeah I agree and I would like to. We are anxious to try that though. The site is in production and it might take time to fully test to see if nothing's broken. We can't afford that extra time right now. =)

Answer (score 1):

I had to restart Visual Studio after Azure SDK install. **ServiceHostingSDKBinDir** was set fine in msbuild, but not in the VS.

Comment: Had the same issue after instalation. Make sure to restart VS.

Answer (score 0):

I added C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure.NET SDK\v2.3 (or whatever sdk you need eg. 2.2, 2.4) to the system path and it fixed the issue of VS2013 not being able to find the SDK.

After I'd changed the system path, I had to restart VS2013.